# Figma sign off processes – best practices?

Tags: team

Are there any best practices to documenting and signing off design decisions made by the leadership team? Oftentimes an issue we face is that design decisions get lost and when we look back we are unable to trace why we made certain design decisions.

I'm wondering if the save version feature and naming it right in Figma would help.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about tool usage best practices and not a general UX question

Answer (score 1):

Use docs (like a Product Requirements Document) for documenting key aspects and decisions of design initiatives, not Figma. Mention people when you make an important change.

In my experience, good communication is the most overlooked and most problematic thing in design teams. It's hard to get it right, but some conventions and rituals can help. Good luck!